# Getting an app rank from the Apple AppStore

Tags: app-store

I'm playing around with the AppStore search API and I was wondering why the API is returning different results (in terms of ranking) than when searched on the AppStore on an iPhone. I'm using the following query:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=google&country=us&entity=software&limit=200

When I type in the search term on my iPhone I get most of the time the same result for position one and two but then the lists start differing. I thought the order of the results in the JSON is the ranking. But unfortunately it is not. Is there a way to get the exact ranking via an API call?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I’m looking for the same thing. Thanks.